# How can I solve the circular dependency problem between the following DAX queries?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

A circular dependency has been detected and I can't seem to understand why there is a circular dependency

```
Jeuniors = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Feuille Import'[Valeur commune] ),
    'Feuille Import'[Attribut]
        IN {
        "Pop Entre 60 ans et 64 ans 2019",
        "Pop Entre 65 ans et 69 ans 2019",
        "Pop Entre 70 ans et 74 ans 2019"
    }
)
```

```
Jeunes = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Feuille Import'[Valeur commune] ),
    'Feuille Import'[Attribut]
        IN {
        "Pop Moins de 20 ans 2019",
        "Pop Entre 20 ans et 24 ans 2019"
    }
)
```

Comment: Well, those two measures by themselves do not indicate a circular dependency. Suggest you investigate further and amend your post with additional information which may help.